# React Native use full vertical area under Android OS bar

Tags: android, react-native, user-interface, native, user-experience

The top of my app has a large empty space around the Android OS bar. Pictured is the official Android Studio emulator as a Pixel 5 API 30 running my app:

[image: Top of my application]

However, the same emulator running Google Maps shows that their app is able to utilize the vertical space behind the Android OS bar:

[image]

#### How might I accomplish this in React Native?

---

*Note:* the iOS build of my same app does in fact make use of the vertical area under the iOS OS bar, similar to what is shown in the Maps screenshot. I did not have to deliberately choose the behavior, it just seems to be the default for iOS 13+

Comment: Its probably not the default on Android because its not the default for Android apps in general.  You should really only be doing this if you have a particular need for your app.  It's not normal behavior on this OS.

Comment: But here's a tutorial on it.  You cannot do this at the RN layer, you'll have to do it at the android layer. https://proandroiddev.com/android-full-screen-ui-with-transparent-status-bar-ef52f3adde63